# DB2 Transactions - Commit everything or rollback

Tags: transactions, db2

I have a SQL Script that have multiple Inserts/Updates/Deletes and I want to guarantee that it only commits if all statements run with success.

I think the Database has the autocommit set a True and since I'm not the one responsible to manage it, I can't change it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your environment, what is the script processor? It is a setting on the transaction level and can be changed for the script.

Comment: Autocommit is controlled at the session (connection) level, so you can set it according to your requirements. The actual method of changing this setting depends on your client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the SQL-script to the Db2-command-line processor (db2 clp) then you can use either a command-line option to disable commit, or you can enable or disable the autocommit on the fly inside the script.

To disable autocommit on the Db2 CLP command line:  use `db2 +c -stvf scriptfile.sql`

To disable autocommit inside the script file:

```
update command options using c off;    --disable autocommit

insert... ;

update ...;

commit;
```

If you are submitting the script to a different processor, you need to specify which script-processor you are using, as different tools have different methods to specify these things.